# need help calling a remote server with JSP

Tags: jsp

I'm writing an application in JSP that needs to reach out to a remote cgi which will feed it some data.

Is there a JSP specific way to do this that is less brute force than simply using the httpConnection library and reading a bitstream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) [`<c:import>`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/import.html) tag to import response data from external resources in your JSP page.

```
<c:import url="http://example.com/some.cgi" />
```

But if this returns a complete HTML page of which you just need a certain part, then you really need to do a bit more work. Best way would be to create a `Servlet` class which preprocesses this data before forwarding the request to the JSP page. You can use [`java.net.URL`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) to get an `InputStream` from it which you feed to a HTML parser to get the necessary information out of it. Here's a basic example:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    InputStream input = new URL("http://example.com/some.cgi").openStream();
    String relevantData = parseHtml(input); // Do your thing here. Maybe with help of jTidy?
    request.setAttribute("data", data);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("page.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

and then in JSP just access the `data` by [EL](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html):

```
<p>Relevant data: ${data}</p>
```

**Edit**: as per the comments, you need the `<c:import>` in combination with the `var` attribute. You can then use [`fn:split()`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/split.fn.html) afterwards to split the obtained `key:value` string.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>

<c:import url="http://example.com/some.cgi" var="result" />
<c:set value="${fn:split(result, ':')}" var="parts" />
key: ${parts[0]}<br>
value: ${parts[1]}<br>
```

Comment: the <c:import> looks like it would do the trick. The cgi is, in fact, returning a key:val string. So, the only caveat would be that I would need to be able to load this result into a String that I can then work with... is that doable or is it only willing to print the result to the page?

Comment: If you click the `c:import` link in my answer, you'll find the tlddoc which states that you can store this in a string `var`.